# Get byte array of Excel sheet from web service and display it in HTML

Tags: java, html, excel, web-services, rest

I need to display Excel sheet in HTML page but Excel sheet is not located in local storage, it's from web service. I can get Excel sheet as a byte array from the below web service.

```
@Path("/getGuruHoldings")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public byte[] getGuruHoldings(@FormParam("guruId") String guruId) {
    String response = "SUCCESS";
    int guru = Integer.parseInt(guruId);
    List<GuruHoldingDTO> list = guruService.getGuruHoldings(guru);
    ExcelCreateHelper createHelper = new ExcelCreateHelper();
    /** method to convert list values into excel sheet byte array */
    byte[] fos = createHelper.guruHoldingExcel(list);
    return fos;
}
```

http://localhost:8081/myguru/gurudata/getGuruHoldings

I can get Excel sheet byte array from this link. I need to display it in full HTML page.

Comment: Is GuruService/GuruHolding part of your code or public API. If not please provide that code.

Comment: You are asking for converting a byte array (`byte[]`) representing an Excel sheet to HTML with tables (`<table>`),  is that it ?

Comment: @Gaël yes, you are right.

Comment: @bkausbk yes, it's part of my code.

Comment: Then have a look to POI (https://poi.apache.org/) for handling Excel documents but I don't think there is already something to convert to an HTML table, you'll have to write it yourself.